# Get absolute path of current .py file in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pathlib

Im trying to get the absolute path of a .py file to access an other file which is located in the same directory (`/files`). All files are mounted in a docker container as part of a jenkins pipeline. In the .py file I use the following syntax to get the absolute path:

```
    from pathlib import Path

    current_dir = f"{Path(__file__).resolve().parent}/result.txt"
```

The file exists in the container but im receiving the following error:

```
No such file or directory: '/tmp/.tmpAA7qY3/files/result.txt'
```

The Jenkins file looks like this:

```
node('docker') {
    docker.image("circleci/python:3.7-buster").inside('--user root:root'+' -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock') {
        stage("Scan dependencies") {
            checkout scm
            sh 'poetry run pytest'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's start with `__file__`. Is your .py code really in /tmp/process-executionIAD8DJ/files? That seems like a weird ending for a folder as I would have expected a package folder name for example.

Comment: Also, please include your Dockerfile. It would help to see the entire workflow.

Comment: You will need something like this.
`fpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "result.txt")`

Assuming `result.txt` and this script are in `files` folder

Comment: @astrochun the .py code is located in the directory /files inside the container. I think instead of using the path starting with /files, it tries to somehow resolve the mount directory of docker volumes.

Comment: @HectorLorenzo Have you set the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile? Can you share the contents of the dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jenkins` will create a new temporary folder which is called `workspace` for each specific build instance. Therefore your code is really in `/tmp/.tmpAA7qY3`. Since you are running in the tmp folder, it's not strange that the `__file__` will resolve to that path.

You need to find out where exactly the file you are searching will be located relative to your temporary folder, or as an absolute path. If you are not in control of how the file was created, easiest is to execute the `find / -name result.txt` and get the result.

If the file is created in another stage in the `Jenkins` pipeline flow, the file might not be in the container since each stage can create it's own container as explained [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).